# check if a file exist with -f and convert the result into variable

Tags: bash, scripts, ls

trying to make  the follwoing command to look for a full fine name work correctly but i can't for now.

The command i use to look for file "Lista*":

---

```
PathFileIN_Elab=/root/Testms/Files

ChkFileName="$(ls -1 -f $PathFileIN_Elab/"$line"* |xargs basename)"
[ -f "${ChkFileName}" ] && echo "File exist"; echo  "Err: $?"; NomeFil="${ChkFileName}" || echo "File does not exist"; echo "Err: $?"
echo ValNomeFileFullExt: "${ChkFileName}"
```

---

Result when file "Lista*"exist:

---

Err: 1

Err: 0

ValNomeFileFullExt: Lista.txt

---

++ I do not see any of my echos for file exist or not but the return code "err" for both cases... why?

Result when file "Lista*" do not exist:

---

ls: impossibile accedere a /root/Testms/Files/Lista*: No such file or directory
basename: missing operand

Usare `basename --help' per ulteriori informazioni.

Err: 1

Err: 0

ValNomeFileFullExt:

---

++ no echos for file exist or not + return code as before plus the basename message

What i'm trying to do is to have a good check of the file name (if exist with extension or not) and set it as a var that i will need after that check, and so:

a) So if the file exist i set the var with full name: NomeFil="${ChkFileName}"

b) if the file do not exist i would like to run a command (ny now in test it's just an echo).

Can somebody help me? i'm new on bash scripts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want the path in with the file name? you know bash scripts dont have to be 1 line right?

Comment: I do not want the path shown in the output but just the whole file name. I would even do the in a different way (not all in one line), but im not sure how to do it.

Comment: One of the problems i noticed; when i look the file with wildcard "Lista*", i see that the echos do not work well. But i still need to use the wild card to intercept the whole file name that could be with or without extention.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating directories or files under `/root`. If you insist on doing so you usually have to prefix your commands with `sudo`. Create your directories and files under `~/home` which you have ownership privileges to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using matching you can expect zero or more answers back, so it is good to use a `for` loop to test one object at a time or it will break your `-f` test statement.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

a="Lista*"
b="/root/Testms/Files/$a"

for c in $b; do
   [[ -f $c ]] && { d=1; break; }
done
[[ $d ]] && { echo File exists; \
              echo ValNomeFileFullExt: $(basename "$c"); } || \
              echo File does not exists
```